# Tinting Towards or Away from a Hue By a Certain Percentage

Tags: c#, image, gdi+, hsl

I'm trying emulate the [Tint Effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.drawing.tinteffect.aspx) of Open XML. What it does is change the hue of pixels in an image by shifting the hue. It takes 2 parameters: 1) the `hue` (in degrees) and 2) the `amt` (the amount, a percentage). It is #2 that I'm having issues with. The spec states:

> **Tint**: Shifts effect color values either towards or away from hue by the
>   specified amount.
>
> - **amt** (Amount) - Specifies by how much the color value is shifted.
> - **hue** (Hue) - Specifies the hue towards which to tint.

Never minding the XML construction, I can emulate values that have an `amt` of 100%. So for example, if I want Blue (hue: 240°), I can create this (the ***Tinted*** one). Here's an example:

**Original** and **Tinted** (hue = 240, Amount = 100%).
[image: Original] [image: Modified]

This is achieved simply by setting the hue to 240, keeping saturation and luminance the same and converting to RGB and writing each pixel.

Here's what I can't achieve though:

Hue=**240** (***blue***), Amount = **30%**, **50%** and **80%**, respectively
[image: 30%] [image: 50%] [image: 80%]

Again, the spec for `Amount` says *Specifies by how much the color value is shifted*. I've tried all sorts of ways here to get this to work, but can't seem to (`hue=hue*amount`, `originalhue * amount + hue`, etc.)

More examples: Hue=**120** (***green***), Amount = **30%**, **50%**, **80%** and **100%**, respectively. The **100%** one I can get.
[image: 30%] [image: 50%] [image: 80%] [image: 100%]

Here are some value lists of a single pixel in the pictures above:

#### Pixel 159, 116 - Blue Pictures

```
        Hue    Amount    R    G    B    | H    S     L
Original                 244  196   10  |  48  0.92  0.5
Blue    240     30%      237   30   45  | 356  0.85  0.52
Blue    240     50%      245    9  156  | 323  0.93  0.5
Blue    240     80%      140   12  244  | 273  0.91  0.5
Blue    240    100%       12   12  244  | 240  0.91  0.5
```

#### Pixel 159, 116 - Green Pictures

```
        Hue    Amount    R    G    B    | H    S     L
Original                 244  196   10  |  48  0.92  0.5
Green    120     30%     211  237   30  |  68  0.85  0.52
Green    120     50%     159  237   30  |  83  0.85  0.52
Green    120     80%      81  237   29  | 105  0.85  0.52
Green    120    100%      29  237   29  | 120  0.85  0.52
```

***So, the question is: Does anyone know how this should work?***

> Note: This is *not* a duplicate of:
>
> - [Changing the tint of a bitmap while    preserving the overall
>     brightness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347840/changing-the-tint-of-a-bitmap-while-preserving-the-overall-brightness)
> - [Rotate Hue using ImageAttributes in    C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079820/rotate-hue-using-imageattributes-in-c)
> - ...or anything else I could find on SO

Comment: Have you tried `hue = ((hue - originalHue) * amount) + originalHue` ?

Comment: @jball: I have. With `hue=240` and `amt=50%` this produces a red sky (originally blue) and bright lime green on the penguin neck color (originally orange and yellow).

Comment: Have you tried interpolating the hue using the method suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416560/hsl-interpolation?

Comment: @kloffy: I have tried it. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am quite certain that your problem results from the way you are interpolating angles. Here's an interpolation function (written in python) that should do the trick. It is based on a suggestion from the xna forums thread [Shortest 2D Angle Interpolation](http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/53551/324957.aspx).

```
def wrap(value, lower, upper):
    distance = upper - lower
    return value - ((value-lower)//distance)*distance

def shortestangle(a,b):
    angle = wrap(b-a, 0, 360)
    if angle>=180: angle -= 360
    return angle

def interpolate(a,b,amount):
    return (a+shortestangle(a,b)*amount)%360
```

Now, `interpolate(originalHue,hue,amount)` should produce the desired result.

*Edit:* It is my understanding that your goal is to rotate the original hue towards a certain target hue by some given amount. I'm sure you're already familiar with this, but for the sake of illustration, here's a color wheel.

[image: Color Wheel]
<sub>(source: [sapdesignguild.org](http://www.sapdesignguild.org/resources/glossary_color/images/color_wheel2.jpg))</sub>

The problem is that mixing (or interpolating) two angles is not trivial, so code like `hue = ((hue - originalHue) * amount) + originalHue` will not work. There is an infinite number of ways you can go from one angle to another because of the wraparound at 360°. To get from 0° to 60° you could rotate 60° counter-clockwise, 420° counter-clockwise, 300° clockwise etc. Usually the shortest angle is the desired one.

For example, lets consider the penguin necks: if your original hue is 30° (orange), your target is 240° (blue) and the amount is 50%, you would get the following results:

```
//Linear Interpolation
(30° + (240° - 30°)*0.5) = 135° (green)

//"Shortest 2D Angle Interpolation"
(30° + shortestangle(30°,240°)*0.5) % 360 = (30° + (-150°)*0.5) % 360 = 315° (magenta)
```

My guess is that the second result is the one you are looking for, but I may be wrong and the error could be somewhere else entirely...

Comment: Thanks kloffy for the response. Unfortunately, I'm having a difficult time understanding how Lerp is related to the issue. I just ported the Python example over to VBA (just to be quick about it) and it's not really telling me anything I don't already know (i.e. the interpolated value). How does Lerp relate to the issue in order to produce the desired results?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the further editing and explanation. The angle interpolation certainly gets very close to expected results for a new hue. Any thoughts on the saturation and luminance differences?

Comment: You're welcome. The differences in saturation and luminance do not make a lot of sense to me. According to my interpretation of the specification they should stay constant. The only possible explanation I can come up with is that they are artifacts resulting from the conversion from HSL to RGB and back.

Comment: Great. I'll continue to test this in the coming days to see if I can get all HSL components - but the angle interpolation is a great start.

Comment: I think you're right, after much testing it appears that the L/S differences are just artifacts. Thanks for all the help here!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [TintParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534074(v=VS.85).aspx) in GDI+ (not part of .NET though) - this may be just what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh, this is very interesting, I didn't know it was part of GDI+ (or at least non-flat GDI+). I'd like to be able to calculate this on my own, but barring figuring that out, may end up resorting to PInvoke.